# Why input number change the visual properties when adding max property?

Tags: html, css

When I add the max property to an number input, the table calculate the width of the cell differently.
It destroys the style of a table in my project, making things not consistent.

I search in the inspector any style difference, but nothing.

So, how can I make the table to have consistent widths for each cell using max property in just some inputs and taking advantage of table responsive behaviour? (unknown numbers of cols)

I would be happy to understand what is going on too.

```css
table {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type="number"] {
  width: 90%;
}

td{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<table>

  <tr>
    <td><input min="0" type="number"></td>
    <td><input min="0" type="number"></td>
    <td><input min="0" type="number"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input min="0" type="number"></td>
    <td><input min="0" type="number"></td>
    <td><input min="0" type="number"></td>
  </tr>

</table>

<table>

  <tr>
    <td><input min="0" type="number"></td>
    <td><input min="0" max="100" type="number"></td>
    <td><input min="0" max="100" type="number"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input min="0" type="number"></td>
    <td><input min="0" max="100" type="number"></td>
    <td><input min="0" max="100" type="number"></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

i am using Win10 - Google Chrome Version 83.0.4103.97 (Official Build) (64-bit)

in the new Edge(based on chromium) is happening too.

Firefox is showing thing as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Change `width: 90%` to anything pixel related or set a specific width of the parent element then it should work fine.

Comment: sorry, i didn't mention that i want the table to be responsive to parent width changes. i will update the question.